# Text alignment on button control

Tags: vb.net

I am working on porting an Access application to vb.net. One of the constraints is that the user forms should look the same. For the most part I managed to get it right, except for the button captions, the text property in vb.net.

It looks like the button control in vb.net has some sort of default margin on the control surface. No matter what I use for the text alignment it will truncate the text and move it to the next line. The text itself fits the size of the control.

I have been playing with the onpaint event of the button but have been unable to get t to do what I want.

So I guess I am looking for a way to either redraw the button text on the control the way I want it or change the default margin on the button surface so the control text is not truncated.

Any help to point me in right direction will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: making the button wider. is it an option for you?

Comment: or use smaller font size

Comment: No I am afraid it is not, because of the constraint I mentioned. It would also mean a redesign of the form to make it bigger. The font in the given size would almost be to small to read if I make small so it does fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In button's properties, try to set `FlatStyle` to `System`.

Comment: Me.ButtonName.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System, seems to do it. No idea that it would be that simpel! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `UseCompatibleTextRendering` for the button to true.

[image]

[image]

It is basically a leftover from the old days of .NET 1 and it differs in the way the text is drawn and measured (either by GDI+ or by GDI). It may help in your case as well.

Comment: No I tried it and it makes no difference. Thanks for the suggestion.